# Shibboleth Session Validation In Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, saml, shibboleth

I have an Apache/2.2.15 web server with the modules, mod_shib, mod_ssl, and mod_jk. I have a virtual host which is configured (attached below) with AuthType Shibboleth, SSLCertificates, and JKMount to direct requests using AJP to my Tomcat 8 server after a session is successfully established with the correct IDP. When my http request reaches my app server, I can see the various Shib-* headers, along with the attributes my SP requested from the IDP.

Is there a way my app server can validate the *shibsession* cookie or other headers? I am trying to protect against the scenario where my web server, which resides in the DMZ is somehow compromised, and an attacker makes requests to my app server, which resides in an internal zone.

Is there a way I can validate a signature of something available in the headers, to guarantee that the contents did indeed originate from the IDP, and were not manufactured by an attacker who took control of my web server?

Is there something in the OpenSAML library I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way my app server can validate the shibsession cookie or other headers?

mod_shib has already done that difficult work for you. After validating the return of information from the Identity Provider (IdP), mod_shib then sets environment variables (cannot be set by the client) for your application to read and trust. Implementing OpenSAML in your application is unnecessary as mod_shib has done the validation work for you.

From the [docs](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess):

> The safest mechanism, and the default for servers that allow for it,
>   is the use of environment variables. The term is somewhat generic
>   because environment variables don't necessarily always imply the
>   actual process environment in the traditional sense, since there's
>   often no separate process. It really refers to a set of controlled
>   data elements that the web server supplies to applications and that
>   cannot be manipulated in any way from outside the web server.
>   Specifically, the client has no say in them.

Comment: Thank you and I understand that mod_shib does that, but even according to the attached evidence you gave "...cannot be manipulated in any way from outside the web server" The attack vector I am concerned with is if the web server itself is compromised!  In my scenario the web server I planned on putting mod_shib on lived in a DMZ, and the app server in a more secure internal zone further fire-walled off, with acls etc. However, I was looking for something in Shibboleth that I could further leverage to establish trust between either the app server and the web server, or the app server and idp.

Comment: You want to do the work of taking apart the SAML assertion and seeing if the information is genuine on a trusted server. If you don't trust the web server, don't use mod_shib on that server. Either use mod_shib on a trusted server or do your own SAML work with OpenSAML directly in your application.

Comment: Thank you again. The options on the table right now are 1) Move the web server which is running mod_shib to the same zone as the app server as you suggest 2) have the IDPs send an attribute that is signed, which my app server can verify. Generally option 2 would be hard to achieve but since my list of IDPs is small and I can influence them easily, it is a possibility. Using OpenSAML directly seems more difficult and prone to error on my part, to get it right. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, validating the signatures is difficult work especially if you are receiving assertions from various IdPs like Shibboleth, simpleSaml, and ADFS. Each assertion will be a bit different. If the IdP software is consistent, this will be less work. There are some solid libraries out there also like spring-security-saml.